# Google goals are tracking but the label is not showing up in GA. How to fix it so the label does come over in GA

Tags: google-analytics

I attached GA event tracking to a tab on the home of the website. http://www.positivepromotions.com/

```
<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'weeklySpecial', 'Click', 'weeklySpecialTab']); window.location='http://www.positivepromotions.com/weekly-special/a/315/'"></a>
```

When looking in goal results in GA I get the "/" in my results. I have checked my set up in GA and it is set to label that matches weeklySpecialTab.

What am i doing wrong? I would like the label name to show in my reports.

Answer (score 0):

The reports gives you the page where the event was triggered (which is in your case always the homepage /). I guess the easiest way for you would be a custom report:

> Customization->New Custom Report -> Dimension "Event Label" -> (other
>   Dimensions at your liking) -> Metric "Goal Completion X" (replace X
>   with the numeric index of the goal) -> Filter "Event Category" set to
>   "weeklySpecial".

I don't think the report you want is available in the standard reports.